# manjaro not showing desktop files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manjaro, desktop

I have manjaro 20.1.1 installed alongside ubuntu 20.04. They share the same home partition. There is a `Desktop` directory and Ubuntu has no problem recognizing it and showing the files inside it on the desktop.

But Manjaro doesn't. In Manjaro, there is nothing on the desktop and when I right click the desktop, I can only see three options: `Change background; Display settings; Settings`. I expect to see something like 'Create A New File' but there isn't one. The the `nautilus` doesn't show the `Desktop` directory on the left side pane either.

I tried setting the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` but no luck.

Both ubuntu and manjaro run the gnome desktop environment.

I don't know what's going on with my manjaro. What should I do to fix the manjaro desktop folder? What could be the possible cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [manjaro forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-not-showing-files-in-home-desktop/30338). It turns out that the default behavior of latest gnome is to not show the files on the desktop. If you want to see files on your desktop, you need to install gnome extension `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`.